# continuity of f(x) over Q

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Is there a way to prove with a $\epsilon/\delta$ proof that $f: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$, defined by

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 - 2}$

is continuous for all $x$ in $\mathbb Q$.

What I’ve tried so far;

To satisfy the $\epsilon/\delta$ definition of continuity, we need to find a $\delta$ such that if $|x-a|$ < $\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|$ < $\epsilon$.

We can manipulate the expression
$$
\begin{split}
\left|\frac{1}{x^2 - 2} - \frac{1}{c^2 - 2}\right| &= \left|\frac{c^2 - x^2}{(x^2 - 2)(c^2 - 2)}\right| = \frac{|c-x||c+x|}{|x^2 - 2||c^2 - 2|}\\
&=
|c-x|\frac{|c+x|}{|x^2 - 2||c^2 - 2|}
\end{split}
$$

From here on I am little lost. I know we can control this part $|c-x|$, and make it as small as we want. The other part, $\frac{|c+x|}{|x^2 - 2||c^2 - 2|}$, I dont know what to do with.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sure thing I’ll add what I’ve tried so far!

Comment: $1/(x^2-2)$ as a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=\pm\sqrt 2$. Do you know how to prove that? The same $\delta(\epsilon)$ choice will work when restricting to $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$, $q\in\mathbb Q$, and put $g(x)=x^2-2$. Since $g$ is obviously continuous and $|g(q)|>0$, we can find $\delta_1>0$ s.t. $|g(q)-g(x)|<\frac{1}{2}|g(q)|$ whenever $x\in(q-\delta_1,q+\delta_1)$. Note that in this case we have $|g(x)|>\frac{1}{2}|g(q)|$. We can also find $\delta_2>0$ s.t. $|g(q)-g(x)|<\frac{1}{2}|g(q)|^2\epsilon$ for $x\in(q-\delta_2,q+\delta_2)$. Hence for $\delta=min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ and $x\in(q-\delta,q+\delta)$ we have $|\frac{1}{g(q)}-\frac{1}{g(x)}|=|\frac{g(x)-g(q)}{g(x)g(q)}|<\frac{2|g(x)-g(q)|}{|g(q)|^2}<\epsilon$. Since $f=\frac{1}{g}$ on $\mathbb Q$, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get one factor small, you just need to bound the other one. The numerator can be bounded pretty easy with the triangle inequality.
Now you just need to choose your $\delta>0$ small enough to keep the denominator away from 0.

Does that help or do you need another hint?

Unrelated to the question: Using \cdot instead of * yields a $\cdot$.

Comment: Okay. We can bound the numerator by |f(x)| > 1/2⋅|f(a)|, right? I’m not sure with the numerator though

Comment: I m not sure what you mean. You can use the triangle inequality for the numerator. For the denominator you have to choose $\delta$ small enough, such that $a$/$c$ is not too close to $\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant we can control the factor |f(x)| by setting |f(x)| > 1/2⋅|f(a)|. How would you bound the numerator?